# gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libtalloc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: display-settings

system; ubuntu 20.04.3 Raspberry PI 4B
attempting to set gnome-control-center settings. consistent errors.
Persist in all attempts to install or run anything.
gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libtalloc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: desktop display installed via xorg.
Later used purge xorg but gnome display remains.

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt install libtalloc2`...